# How to calculate the wire gauge windings when creating my-own PM BLDC Motor, 12N14P, Outrunner motor?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, wiring, gauge, stator

I am using [BLDC Stator](https://www.ebay.com/itm/165055535099?hash=item266e1397fb:g:yR8AAOSw%7E8dhNXdQ) and [BLDC controller](https://www.aliexpress.us/item/2255800780832363.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.6dbe3041hc1BIW&algo_pvid=951f6515-d4fe-4400-8ece-bd649b2bdab7&algo_exp_id=951f6515-d4fe-4400-8ece-bd649b2bdab7-8&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2210000012935233047%22%7D&pdp_pi=-1%3B58.31%3B-1%3B12.15%40salePrice%3BUSD%3Bsearch-mainSearch&gatewayAdapt=glo2usa4itemAdapt&_randl_shipto=US) at 48V @ 27A.[image: Windings for a 12N14P Wye]

Comment: What do you mean by "wire gauge windings"?

Comment: what Gauge wire to use in the Windings of the my BLDC Stator? For example, if it was almost 30Amp, would I need like a 10 AWG wire in the windings, etc.